# apache ofbiz: include existing service in own component

Tags: java, ofbiz

I would like to use an existing service (`createInvoice`)
within an new `ofbiz` component.

In my componentScreens.xml I added:
a section

```
<decorator-section name="body">
                    <section>
                        <widgets>
                            <screenlet     title="${uiLabelMap.AccountingCreateNewSalesInvoice}">
                                <include-form name="NewSalesInvoice" location="component://accounting/widget/InvoiceForms.xml"/>
                                </screenlet>
                            <screenlet     title="${uiLabelMap.AccountingCreateNewPurchaseInvoice}">
                                <include-form name="NewPurchaseInvoice"     location="component://accounting/widget/InvoiceForms.xml"/>
                            </screenlet>
                        </widgets>
                    </section>
                </decorator-section>
```

which is displayed fine. But the `NewPurchaseInovice-form` calls a service `createInvoice`, which is defined in /accounting/servicedef/services_invoice.xml

So when my form calls the service `ofbiz` states an error:

```
org.ofbiz.webapp.control.RequestHandlerException: Unknown request [createInvoice]; this request does not exist or cannot be called directly.
```

One solution might be to redefine (copy) the service in my components
services.xml:

```
    <service name="createInvoice" engine="simple" default-entity-name="Invoice"
    location="component://accounting/script/org/ofbiz/accounting/invoice/InvoiceServices.xml" invoke="createInvoice">
    <description>Create Invoice Record</description>
    <permission-service service-name="acctgInvoicePermissionCheck" main-action="CREATE"/>
    <auto-attributes mode="INOUT" include="pk" optional="true"/>
    <auto-attributes mode="IN" include="nonpk" optional="true"/>
    <override name="invoiceTypeId" mode="IN" optional="false"/>
    <override name="partyIdFrom" mode = "IN" optional="false"/>
    <override name="partyId" mode = "IN" optional="false"/>
    <override name="description" allow-html="safe"/>
    <override name="invoiceMessage" allow-html="safe"/>
</service>
```

But maybe there is an easier solution (maybe there is a way
to specify the location of the service in the request-map?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error `org.ofbiz.webapp.control.RequestHandlerException: Unknown request [createInvoice]; this request does not exist or cannot be called directly.` states that the component cannot find the specified **request**, it's not about the **service** definition. Inside the request definition you specify which **event** or **service** has to be processed.

Your form calls a **request** which has either to be specified in your component's controller.xml or the form's request must point to the accounting component's request which already exists.

You don't have to copy the service definition to use it in you component, OFBiz registers all service definitions by name and handles them for all components.

Comment: Thanks. I added the associated request and it worked!